# Accepting Nominations — Who should Moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

[image: profile for curiousdannii on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

I'll self nominate.

I'm Dannii. I have a linguistics degree, and thought I might be able to help people on this site through explaining linguistic concepts and pointing to natlang examples. I had actually only committed to the site on Area51 about a week before the beta started, and didn't expect that I would find the whole thing so interesting. It's always great to find something new that fascinates you!

I'm not a moderator on any other site in the network, but I am a strong believer in community moderation, and am a top editor and reviewer on many sites. In our short time as a private beta here I've become a one of the top editors, Meta participants, and users by rep. I'd be honoured to be selected as a pro-tem moderator.

Comment: Dannii has been active on this site since day 1, and has taken an active role in the self-moderation of the site. I think he'd be a good choice.

Comment: @Mithrandir Fun fact, due to time zones and sleep, I actually only joined the site on the second day :P

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I am also self-nominating.

I have a linguistics degree and relatively extensive, in-depth experience into formal semantics, pragmatics, social meaning, affective content, and information structure -- all areas of linguistics that are very useful to conlangers but often overlooked in other sites for conlangers. I have contributed and will continue to contribute detailed self-answers to provide this information to the members of the StackExchange. I also am in academia, so as I continue to actively participate in and consume linguistic literature, I can share relevant information from that literature with this community.

I have contributed high quality content to the StackExchange, and though I did not participate during the first two weeks of the private beta for irl personal reasons, I have provided prompt answers (often first answers) to many questions. I have done a very good job digging up sources on the web and in linguistic literature for my answers as well. My answers have typically been very detailed.  While I am relatively new to StackExchange as a whole and only began participating in this private beta rather recently, I have a passion for linguistics and conlanging and have worked hard to find answers for questions that have been neglected. I also have made small edits to questions and titles to improve answerability and have weighed in on opening and closing threads. I have also participated in meta discussions. I have enthusiasm about this site and a level head.

I am known by my friends and by those in other online communities I spend time in as "chill" and "mellow about drama" -- while I am good at listening to others complaints and hearing them out, I don't overreact to trolling and insults, and I only take action when truly necessary. However, when it is clear action needs to be taken, I do not hesitate. I am decisive, firm, and fair.

Obviously, I accept this nomination.

I live in Ohio (USA) and am generally active from 5:00pm to 1:00am EST (that's 22:00--6:00 GMT).

Comment: Are you serious? You are (with your account) no longer than 24 days on the stackexchange network and don't seem to have gathered a lot of experience. This self-nomination is your first post on this meta as well. Hmmm....

Comment: @jknappen This is not my first post on this meta. I won't claim I've been particularly active, but a quick look at my (linked) profile will show this is not my first post. I admitted to being relatively new to StackExchange. I self-nominated because I am enthusiastic about this site and about conlanging. I'm all for it if they choose moderators with more experience, but I'm not taking away from more experienced candidates by throwing my hat in the ring. If you prefer other candidates, upvote or nominate them. I'm not sure what your comment is intended to accomplish besides insult me.

Comment: @jknappen A mix of fresh voices and prior experience consistently makes for the best moderation teams. Good leadership needs people who can take a new view on problems of site policy.

Comment: I upvoted this nomination. Even if you don't know the SE system inside out at this point, subject matter expertise is a good thing to have on a mod team as well.

Comment: I first started as a mod after only a short time on the network (a bit longer than this, but not by a huge amount). Network experience is always great, but commitment to a young site is also important. I think Sparksbet has led by example in their posts on the main site, and I'd definitely support this nomination.

Comment: Hi, I attempted to reach out to you via email last week but never received a response. Could you see if you received the message or if perhaps it's in a spam folder somewhere?

Comment: @animuson I'm so sorry! It did get caught in a spam filter -- I'll respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I am self-nominating.

I am a moderator on [/r/conlangs](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/) as well as an experienced conlanger. I have been active on the SE since the beginning, doing my duties with cleaning up queues and what not (though in the past week or so there wasn’t much to do and I haven’t quite settled back into school life yet, hence my lack of recent activity).

While I am not very familiar with StackExchange per se, I have read through all the relevant guidelines I am aware of. I hope to be able to shape this site in a positive direction (which I believe may have to deviate a bit from the usual stackexchange standard due to conlanging being such a creative field). As a moderator on the largest conlanging forum there is (the aforementioned subreddit), I am aware of the janitorial roles a moderator has to fulfill, but I do not mind them if they in turn give me the possibility to shape the community in a positive way.

My apologies for the late entry.

Comment: Hi, I attempted to reach out to you via email last week but never received a response. Could you see if you received the message or if perhaps it's in a spam folder somewhere?

Comment: @animuson Hi, this indeed is the case. I wrote a response just now.

Comment: @animuson It's strange that your mails are caught by spam filters. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Zyerah is a current pro-tem mod on [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) SE and former mod (both pro-tem and elected) on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) SE. I've known her as a moderator for many years, and never seen her lose their head, even when moderating very difficult situations. Her moderation is firm but fair - she will criticise people when necessary, but always in as kind a way as possible, and she doesn't hold grudges.

She's also been active on both ConLang SE and its meta, and she seems to share the same enthusiasm for and knowledge about this topic as the topics of puzzling and literature.

**Accepted:**

Zyerah's response:

> Thank you sincerely for the nomination - it means a lot to me. I would be happy to moderate if I am called to the position. It may be important for voters, and SE, to know that I may not have a whole lot of time soon, and may not be able to play as active a hand in site development as an early beta needs. I haven't been able to participate on site much recently, either. That being said, this is a fairly quiet beta, and it's hard to imagine pressing issues being common. I might reconsider, but I will hesitantly accept.

Comment: Thank you sincerely for the nomination - it means a lot to me. I would be happy to moderate if I am called to the position. It may be important for voters, and SE, to know that I may not have a whole lot of time soon, and may not be able to play as active a hand in site development as an early beta needs. I haven't been able to participate on site much recently, either. That being said, this is a fairly quiet beta, and it's hard to imagine pressing issues being common. I might reconsider, but I will hesitantly accept.

Comment: I moderate alongside Zyerah, and she has proven herself to be reasonable, capable, and an excellent moderator. We've been working together for a year now, and I'm honored to be working alongside her.

Comment: I think being a current mod and former mod here will be good to have moderating this site.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Mithrandir]

[image: Mithrandir][image: profile for Mithrandir on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

I'll throw my hat in the ring.

I'd be interested in becoming a mod here on ConLang.SE. I've been following the site since the Area 51 stage, and I was relatively active in attempting to get it off the ground (and succeeded in referring 9 users to commit). Once it got off the ground, I participated in the private beta, contributing posts, comments, reviews, and whatnot.

I have experience with the SE system, having been active on SE since 2014, the flagging system, having raised 10k+ helpful flags network-wide, and with the moderator tools, having been a moderator on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com) for the past year.

I'd be interested in helping moderate this site, and I hope my record will speak for itself.

Comment: Three downvotes on this self nomination... if anyone has concerns about Mirthrandir it would be good to actually voice them.

Comment: I second this.  Mithrandir is an awesome mod on literature and an active contributor on this site--and he's obviously enthusastic to become a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

I nominate Gufferdk.

[image]

[image]

Solid knowledgeable user, pretty good posts, would be a good moderator if he/she can keep this level altogether with the tools. And, of course, if he/she wants/can do it.

**Accepted:**

I happily accept this nomination, and I'm happy someone would take the effort to nominate me. I had considered nominating myself but decided against it due to some social anxiety, but seeing as there is support from at least some of the community, to the point where they will nominate me changes things.

@curiousdannii re:meta participation, I've looked at it and voted on some things, but there haven't been a much by way of posts where an answer already posted didn't already cover more or less what I wanted to say on the issue.

Comment: I know guffer from other communities, he’s both knowledgable and very keen to help out. He’s one of the most active posters on [/r/conlangs](https://www.reddit.com/r/conlangs/)’ small discussions thread, i.e. the place where all the “beginner questions” go.

Comment: I happily accept this nomination, and I'm happy someone would take the effort to nominate me. I had considered nominating myself but decided against it due to some social anxiety, but seeing as there is support from at least some of the community, to the point where they will nominate me changes things.
@curiousdannii re:meta participation, I've looked at it and voted on some things, but there haven't been a much by way of posts where an answer already posted didn't already cover more or less what I wanted to say on the issue.

Answer (score -5):

**DECLINED**

[image]

[image]

[image: profile for HDE 226868 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because he is already a moderator on [Worldbuilding.se](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), which is another site where a balance between creativity and the question & answer format needs to be maintained.

Comment: HDE also moderates Interpersonal Skills, History of Science and Mathematics, and Mythology, in addition to Worldbuilding, and has proven themselves to be a capable and responsible moderator.

Comment: I appreciate this, but for now, I'll have to decline. I moderate four sites already, which is . . . a bit much; also, I so far haven't given Constructed Languages the attention I wish I could have. Unless we don't get three good nominations here - and I think we will - I'll decline the nomination. Thanks.

Comment: I'm downvoting this not because I think he'd be bad at the job (quite the opposite) but only because he's declined - let the top answers be people who are actually happy to step up.

Comment: I think there is no need for further downvotes, the purpose of them is already fulfilled.